# Express is not showing any params being received from a POST request

Tags: node.js, express

In node, I'm using express.router() to receive a curl request. I just want to do a "hello world" and log whatever I've received

My curl request:

```
curl -F "hello_world=foobar" http://examplesite.com/my_endpoint
```

How Node handles it:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.route('/my_endpoint')
  .post(function(req, res){
    var data = req.body;
    console.log(data); // This comes back blank... shouldn't it have "hello_world=foobar"?
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

req.body doesnt exist naturally within a Express-App. For that, you need express´s body-parser middleware. Install it with:

```
npm install body-parser --save
```

After that, you can easily add it to your app by like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 

var app = express(); // Instantiate an express app
app .use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // parse application/json

var router = app.Router();
router.route('/my_endpoint')
  .post(function(req, res){
    var data = req.body;
    console.log(data); // This comes back blank... shouldn't it have "hello_world=foobar"?
  });
```

**EDIT**
I also saw you have a little mistake by how you are instantiating your express app. You dont use the router on express itself, but on an app you instantiate before by just calling express. I edited it in my above example.

Answer (score 2):

Experiencing the same challenge in Jan 2020:

Using Express 4.16+.

You no longer need to install `body-parser`.

Instead just add `router.use(express.json());` to the the routing file like so:

```
// in ./routes/routingFile.js:

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
router.use(express.json());         // to support JSON-encoded bodies
```

Now your requests will contain the body.

Comment: Some clients misbehave and don't send the content-type, one option is to make the parser more permissive: app.use(express.json({inflate: true, strict: false, type: () => { return true; } }));

Answer (score 1):

I would do it a little differently,

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express(); 
var http = require('http').Server(app);


app.post('/myendpoint', function (req, res) {
    var body = "";
    req.on('data', function (data) {
        body += data;
    });
    req.on('end', function () {
        console.log(body); //will print hello_world=Foobar
    });
```

Comment: The code is helpful, but can you give an explanation why you would do this a different way?

Comment: @DonnyP First of all, I haven't used express.router(). I always do it this way. And secondly, POST requests are received in two parts, the data comes in chunks, and hence we store it continuously in the body variable. After there is no more data, the POST request sends an end event notifying that there is no more data available.
I guess, you just need to split the request on two different events, data and end, it will work well then.